# Listbox.Length always 0 in JS

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

When I run the following JS I always get the confirm box popping up despite the list visibly having items.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" Width="135px" Rows="8" />

function CheckListEmpty() {
if ($("#list").length == 0) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        //they clicked OK so save and close
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //do nothing they hit cancel.
        return false;
    }
}
else
    return true;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect "#list" to refer to?  What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I expected it to refer to 
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" Width="135px" Rows="8" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#list").length` returns the number of elements matched by the jQuery selector.
It isn't matching anything because you aren't using the ListBox's `ClientId`; you need to change it to `$("#<%= list.ClientId %>")`.

To get the number of items in the `<select>`, you need to write `$("#<%= list.ClientId %> option").length`

Answer (score 1):

The runat="server" causes ASP.NET to dynamically create a unique ID, not the one you assigned. Therefore the ID jQuery selector does not find it. Either add a class and select that or "[id*='ListBox']" to find the ID that contains the ID you specified.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about that. So since it dynamically creates the ID how can I get a reference to that ID?

Comment: This only happens if the control is inside a page that uses a Master page. Although to be sure just view the source of the page to see what the id attribute is

Comment: This page is derived from a Master Page

Answer (score 0):

"length" is not a parameter on SELECT elements in javascript. You can use `(select).elements.length` instead.

Comment: .length is a property of jQuery indicating the number of elements in the selection.

Comment: That's fine, but he's not asking for the number of items that jQuery returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ...

});
```

Always best to place your functions inside this to ensure that the DOM is ready

Comment: This function will be called when the user clicks the save at the bottom of the page so do I really need to do this? I realize for functions that are run on load you should do this.